# iOS. No camera preview in WKWebview video identification (black frame content)

Tags: javascript, ios, video, camera, wkwebview

I have to open a WKView which should access the iPhone camera in order to perform a video identification for a banking app. I load the url using the app's webview engine and I successfully intercept the events it sends. When the camera frame is shown, it asks me for mic/camera permission which I grant and it overlays the circle to fit the face and it seems to recognize and continue to the next event but there's no camera preview and the camera rectangle remains black all the process. I think I've tried every related WKView and WKConfiguration property to no avail. Is this even possible to do in iOS? I'm trying with iOS16 but the app is targeting iOS11+. I'd appreciate any help.